# remove x ticks but keep grid lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Pyplot plot, which I want to add gridlines to. I did this using:

```
plt.grid(True)
```

I then removed my x ticks using:

```
ax1.xaxis.set_visible(False)
```

My x ticks were removed, but so were the x grid lines. I would like them to stay.

Is there a way I can do this please?

Comment: do you want to get rid of the tick marks or the tick labels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(NullFormatter())
```

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
plt.grid(True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
```

It should work. The grid will be intact, but there won't be any tick labels. If you don't want the ticks too, add:

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
```

Comment: you can also add `ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')` to get rid of the black dashes